# How to properly set type of inherited property

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, types, type-conversion

I had abstract base class.

```
public abstract class TurnBasedGameReferee
{
    public ITurnBasedGamePlayer CurrentPlayer { get; private set; }
    public TurnBasedGameField PlayingField { get; protected set; }
    /*snipped*/
}
```

And I had inheriting class:

```
public class TicTacToeReferee : TurnBasedGameReferee { /*snipped*/ }
```

In TicTacToeReferee I supposed to refer to properties like this:

```
(ITicTacToePlayer)this.CurrentPlayer;
(TicTacToeGameField)this.PlayingField;
```

I think, what use of explicit conversions here every time isn't correct.

Is there a way to do so in the context of `TicTacToeReferee`, these `CurrentPlayer` and `PlayingField` were `ITicTacToePlayer` and `TicTacToeGameField` type without using explicit conversion every time?

Comment: Depends on what you´re trying to do with the result after the cast. Anyway casting to an interface is usually a good idea, don´t know what makes you think it´s not. Show those classes code also and what you´re doing with them after the cast.

Comment: You could use generic parameters on the referee to specify the types of player and field. Though I'd probably suggest you avoid the inheritance unless you have a specific use case for it.

Comment: Anyway if you want to access the members of the derived class you *have* to use a cast to that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Maksim Simkin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41594770/767890) answer and your comments you *could* enforce the type safety you want, but at the cost of an extra generic type parameter and added complexity to your solution:

```
public interface ITurnBasedGame { }
public interface ITurnBasedGamePlayer<TGame> where TGame : ITurnBasedGame { }
public abstract class TurnBasedGameField<TGame> where TGame : ITurnBasedGame { }

public abstract class TurnBasedGameReferee<TGame, TPlayer, TField>
    where TGame: ITurnBasedGame
    where TPlayer: ITurnBasedGamePlayer<TGame>
    where TField: TurnBasedGameField<TGame>
{
    public TPlayer CurrentPlayer { get; private set; }
    public TField PlayingField { get; protected set; }
}
```

And now, considering the following types:

```
public class TicTacToeGame : ITurnBasedGame { }
public class TicTacToePlayer : ITurnBasedGamePlayer<TicTacToeGame> { }
public class TicTacToeGameField : TurnBasedGameField<TicTacToeGame> { }
public class ChessGame : ITurnBasedGame { }
public class ChessPlayer : ITurnBasedGamePlayer<ChessGame> { }
public class ChessGameField : TurnBasedGameField<ChessGame> { }
```

The following would be a compile time error:

```
public class TicTacToeReferee: TurnBasedGameReferee<TicTacToeGame, ChessPlayer, ChessGameField> { }
```

All that said, this is certainly not worth it just to avoid casting the interface to the concrete type of the class. If you don't like all the casts, then you could always implement private helper properties to clean up your code a little:

```
public class TicTacToeReferee : TurnBasedGameReferee
{
     private TicTacToePlayer CurrentTicTacToePlayer => CurrentPlayer as TicTacToePlayer;
     private TicTacToeGameField TicTacToePlayingField => PlayingField as TicTacToeGameField;
     ....
}
```

And simply use these properties in your inner implementation.

Comment: I think what private helpers this is just what I needed at the time of asking question. But now im choosing between private helpers and explicit conversion, because after all answers, I don't think what explicit conversion is something bad

Comment: I made [this helpers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpNSq.png). Is it ok to use `new`  and `base` here?

Comment: @KgOfHedgehogs No, that's actually pretty horrible because now your concrete `TicTacTooReferee` breaks the contract of `TurnBasedGameReferee`; you are hiding base class members that should be public. With your code nobody outside your class would be able to call `ticTacToeReferee.CurrentPlayer` and would need to cast it to the base class in order to do so.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm understand

Comment: Sorry for late question, but what if I made it public? They will be callable outside the class, but their type will be not from abstract base, but analogous TicTacToe-inheritor type

Answer (score 2):

You could use Generics.

```
public abstract class TurnBasedGameReferee<TPlayer, TField>
                  where TPlayer : ITurnBasedGamePlayer 
                  where TField : TurnBasedGameField 
{
    public TPlayer CurrentPlayer { get; private set; }
    public TField PlayingField { get; protected set; }
    /*snipped*/
}

public class TicTacToeReferee : TurnBasedGameReferee<ITicTacToePlayer, TicTacToeGameField>
```

It assumes, that `ITicTacToePlayer` inherits from `ITurnBasedGamePlayer` and `TicTacToeGameField` from `TurnBasedGameField` , but i think was what you was meaning.

Comment: Your suggestion is a kind of that i want, but doesn't that mean, what i can accidentally make for example `new TicTacToeReferee<IChessPlayer, ChessField>`? How to handle this?

Comment: you coud, if IChessPlayer and ChessField  implement TurnBased Classes. Is it bad? Chess is a turn based game, You could create new interfaces ITurnBasedNotChess and let your tic-tac-toe player implement it, and chess player not, than you could use this interface in generic class declaration.

Comment: But TicTacToeReferee cannot organize game with ChessField and ChessPlayers, this is why I think it's isn't good. `TicTacToeReferee` must work only with `TicTacToeField` and `ITicTacToePlayer`

Comment: @KgOfHedgehogs Your solution doesn't do any better of a job of enforcing that then this does.